# Android - Tab select is working but UI screen is not getting updated

Tags: android, user-interface, android-tablayout

I have two ViewPager inside one screen. Inner ViewPager have Tablayout inside it. I want to preserve the Tab position, if I scroll outer viewpager.

I am trying to select a tab from tablayout manually while scrolling outer Viewpager. While debugging Tablayout current tab is showing correct selected tab, but UI is not getting updated.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nKMYX.jpg)

Comment: you wanna change icon with text of tab ?

Comment: No. I have one activity which contains ViewPager and I am adding Fragment which contains Viewpager with tablayout. When I am scrolling outer viewpager. I want to preserved tab index. eg. Let's Say, I am going from Profile A to Profile B. That time Tab3 is selected. So When I scrolled to Profile B. Tab3 should get selected. In this case, tab.select() worked but it's not getting reflected on UI.

Comment: Then post your code also for more.